# Landau Pole and gauging of Dirac fermions

Tags: gauge-theory, conformal-field-theory, fermions

Let us focus on 4d spacetime dimensions. It is well known that $N$ free massless Dirac  fermions is conformal invariant. This theory has a $U(1)$ symmetry under which all the fermions have charge 1, i.e. $\psi_i\to e^{i\alpha}\psi_i, i=1, ..., N$. Now, I'd like to consider another theory by gauging this $U(1)$. I just promote the $U(1)$ background field to dynamical field, and integrate it over in the path integral. The partition function is
$$\int Da \exp\left(-\sum_{i=1}^{N}\int \bar\psi_i \gamma^\mu (\partial_{\mu}- ia_{\mu})\psi_i \right). \tag{*}$$
Note that there is no kinetic term for the gauge field from this naive gauging, i.e. the coupling constant $e$ is infinity for the Maxwell term $\frac{1}{e^2}\int f_{\mu\nu}f^{\mu\nu}$. Usually it is said that there is a  Landau pole in $(*)$. Then after RG, the Maxwell term will be dynamically generated, and eventually $e$ will flow to $0$ logarithmically  in the IR.

The questions I have are:

- (I) Is the theory $(*)$ at infinity coupling a well-defined QFT?
- (II) Is it a conformal field theory?  Because $(*)$ is directly obtained by gauging a $U(1)$ global symmetry from a CFT, and moreover there is no obvious dimensionful coupling constant, so I wonder whether it is a CFT as well.

Comment: I don't see any reason why the answers aren't yes and yes, but this is best left to an expert

Comment: The problem is that $(*)$ can be regarded as a UV fixed point of 4d QED ($e\to \infty$), but it is usually said that QED does not have a well-defined UV completion (due to Landau pole).